# How to save file in internal storage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, path, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm trying to save file in internal storage but not getting success. I'm follow [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) doc.
I'm also trying to save recorded audio file in internal storage. when I search save file in device so not getting there.
below code for manifest I have use.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.untitled1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:label="untitled1"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Please help me for what's wrong with my code.

Comment: if you are using the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin, no need to store the image manually because the plugin will automatically store the image taken. Otherwise please also include your saveFile method so that others could see what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks @john for the instant response but I'm just follow the https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files for save file but if i'm checking in device so not getting there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the line
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAG" />`
should be
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think saving a file in the internal storage is unconventional, Files are mostly saved in the external Storage (memory card).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35143602)